# .click method not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I placed smiley button for popping up new window and show smiles

```
<textarea class="chattextarea" placeholder="Type message" name="message" id="message"  ></textarea>
<div class="smileybutton" id="smileybutton"></div>
```

and i wrote script like this

```
jQuery('#smileybutton').click(function() {
        alert("Clickeddddd");
});
```

But the alert is not working.. if i placed another `alert` outside of bracket, it work on page loading.

Comment: You sure, you load script after DOM rendering is complete?

Comment: The code as shown should work just fine.

Comment: Can you add some text to the `smileybutton' div so you have something to click on and see if it works?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9s89vhxt/1/ works fine

Comment: The code shown will only work if the javascript is found after smileybutton in the DOM or if it is written within a $(document).ready() function anywhere in the DOM. If the element doesn't exist by the time, jQuery is trying to hook things up, it won't work.

And as long as jQuery has been linked up correctly as well ;-)

Comment: @MelanciaUK i dont see the jquery library inserted anywhere.... see he tagged his question simply as "javascript"

Comment: the problem with your markup is that you must have a text inside your div or give it a fixed height and width | see my answer below

Comment: @Sharky I just assumed the OP knew the basics, like needing to have the library loaded. It's uncommon to find questions where people show in their code the part where the library is loaded.

Comment: So whats up? If any of the given answers is correct please accept it and if not show us the answer you came up on your own. Or do you still look for an answer?

Comment: jQuery('.smileybutton').live('click',function(){

This code worked for me.. I dnt knw y..i tried all other types.but only this produces the "alert"

Comment: `.live()` is long deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `jQuery` code inside `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(
   function() {
      jQuery('#smileybutton').click(function() {
          alert("Clickeddddd");
      });
   }
);
```

Or

```
jQuery(document).ready(
   function() {
      jQuery('#smileybutton').click(function() {
          alert("Clickeddddd");
      });
   }
);
```

in case you don't want to use the dollar sign.

Also, be sure to include jQuery as suggested by Axel and Sharky.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
```

**Edit (special thanks to Axel and Sharky for pointing this out)**

After short research, it turns out to be even better to put your script inclusions inside the `body` section of your Web page.

Here is JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LSostaric/qjcu8862/.

Comment: why do you suggest "Do it inside the head"?

Comment: @Axel: It's a good practice to have JavaScript and CSS inclusions inside the `head` tag.

Comment: @Luka its a bad practice slowing your page rendering till all js loads. https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: i agree with @Sharky. but its off-topic by now :)

Comment: still off-topic but: [https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html)

Comment: i still miss one point in this answer what about the dimensions or giving some innerText?

Answer (score 0):

PUT the function code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.smileybutton').click(function() {
        alert("Clickeddddd");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not forget to include the jQuery library:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then add your code inside a `document.ready` block:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#smileybutton').click(function()
    {
        alert("Clickeddddd");
    });
});
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6tnmtf75/

**Important:** Somehow give dimensions to your `#smileybutton` so **you have something to click on.** I added some text on my example on jsfiddle. -i assume you have some css applied to it (width/height and a background image of a smiley maybe?)

Comment: please don't edit my answer by just adding line breaks. i dont like to ruin my coding style just because someone may not know how to use the horizontal scroll bar. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be added document.ready as other said. If you add as external javascript file, you need to wrap in

```
$(function(){});
```

And For now, If you don't set width and height of div, it will be zero and no matter wherever you click, it won't attached with DOM. so you might need to set up div width and height as follows;

```
#smileybutton{

 width:100px;
 height:100px; 
}
```

you can look in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8umgm82s/) version.

Comment: you mean `$(function(){});` not `function(){}();`

Answer (score 0):

It will be working if you change the Javascript by:

```
$(function(){
    $('#smileybutton').click(function() {
        alert("Clickeddddd");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, another way to track click event.

```
jQuery('.smileybutton').live('click',function(){
    alert("Clickeddddd");
});
```

Comment: This code worked for me.>>!!!!
All others i tried.........but no response.. I dnt knw y.....

Comment: You may be using a quite old version of jQuery to still be able to use `.live()`.

Comment: @VishnuPrasad if this works and your original didn't work then probably you have more than one element with `id="smileybutton"` and this confuses jquery (remember `id`'s must be unique)

Comment: @Sharky i tried that case also by appending user id wid d class..but dat does not make any output as i wish.I'm searching for it.. y it happed for a true reason.may b helpful for next time